# Setting datagridviewcomboboxcell value

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have following code to bind combo box cell which works properlly:

```
Const colIndex As Integer = 1
        Dim dgvcombo As DataGridViewComboBoxCell
        dgvcombo = gvMain.Rows(_rowindex).Cells("SerialNumber")
        dtGrpBrand = getDataTable("select * from (select SSPERPSerialMaster.ProductID,SSPERPSerialMaster.SizeID,SSPERPSerialMaster.GaugeID, SSPERPSerialMaster.SerialID,SSPERPSerialMaster.SerialNumber,ISNULL(SSPERPSerialEntryOpening.Qty,0)+ISNULL(a.Stock,0) as [Closing Qty] " & _
                        "from SSPERPProductMaster " & _
                        "left join SSPERPSerialMaster on SSPERPSerialMaster.ProductID=SSPERPProductMaster.ProductID " & _
                        "left join SSPERPSerialEntryOpening on SSPERPSerialEntryOpening.SerialID=SSPERPSerialMaster.SerialID and SSPERPSerialMaster.ProductID=SSPERPSerialEntryOpening.ProductID " & _
                        "left join (select SerialId,SUM(ISNULL(case when AL='A' then Qty else - Qty end, 0)) as [Stock] from SSPERPStock group by SerialId) a on a.SerialId=SSPERPSerialMaster.SerialID) a " & _
                        "where a.[Closing Qty]<>0 and a.ProductID=" & gvMain.Rows(_rowindex).Cells("ProductId").Value.ToString() & " and a.SizeID=" & gvMain.Rows(_rowindex).Cells("SizeId").Value.ToString() & " and a.GaugeID=" & gvMain.Rows(_rowindex).Cells("GaugeId").Value.ToString(), CompanyCon)
        dtGrpBrand.Rows.Add()
        dtGrpBrand.Rows(dtGrpBrand.Rows.Count - 1)("SerialNumber") = "-- Select --"
        dtGrpBrand.Rows(dtGrpBrand.Rows.Count - 1)("SerialId") = 0
        dgvcombo.AutoComplete = True
        CType(gvMain.Rows(_rowindex).Cells(colIndex), DataGridViewComboBoxCell).DataSource = dtGrpBrand
        CType(gvMain.Rows(_rowindex).Cells(colIndex), DataGridViewComboBoxCell).DisplayMember = "SerialNumber"
        CType(gvMain.Rows(_rowindex).Cells(colIndex), DataGridViewComboBoxCell).ValueMember = "SerialId"
        CType(gvMain.Rows(_rowindex).Cells(colIndex), DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Value = 0
```

this codes work perfectlly in my application while i have insert mode of data, but when user choose record from list, than i need to bond dynamically that cell of "SerialNumber",
At That time also i am properlly binding datagridviewcimboboxcell through this code, it binds my combobox cell properlly but when i give following code to set value it is not working and give me error:

```
gvMain.Rows(gvMain.Rows.Count - 1).Cells("SerialNumber").Value = dtrow("SerialId")
```

I have also tried following line to get selected value but no solution:

```
CType(gvMain.Rows(gvMain.Rows.Count - 1).Cells("SerialNumber"), DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Value = dtrow("SerialId")
```

Here gvmain is datagridview and dtrow is datarow

Comment: What is the error message that you get?

Comment: Data error for argument exception is unhandled

Answer (score 0):

`dtrow("SerialId")` returns an Object. You are clearly interested in the value, so try `dtrow("SerialId").ToString`

```
gvMain.Rows(gvMain.Rows.Count - 1).Cells("SerialNumber").Value = dtrow("SerialId").ToString
```

Comment: I have search for this error on net but only one solution mostly i get to use Data Error event for grid view but i want to achieve this task with out that

Answer (score 0):

`DataGridViewComboboxCell` has `DataSource` property. Try to set value by using:

```
   Dim lst As New List(Of String)()
   lst.Add(dtrow("SerialId").ToString)
   DirectCast(DataGridView1.Rows(gvMain.Rows.Count - 1).Cells("SerialNumber"), DataGridViewComboBoxCell).DataSource = lst
```

It should resolve the issue.